# Child URL Access but Domain is Blocked

Tags: facebook, squid

I need some help configuring squid.

I have to block access to **facebook.com** but I need to let a local user to be able to access a Child URL like **Facebook.com/ChildURL**

I already made my research and found an answer:

> http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/squid-acl-to-allow-access-to-a-child-url-below-a-blocked-main-url-907740/
>
> ---
>
> acl good_facebook url_regex -i ^https://www.facebook.com/pages/custfbpagedetail
>
> acl ref referer_regex -i custfbpagedetail
>
> http_access allow good_facebook
>
> http_access deny denied_domains !ref

But unfortunately, it's not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It is nonsense to try and allow only one very specific page URL – trying to access that in the browser will trigger load of all kinds of external resources (CSS, JS, Images, …), and those are within completely different paths.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the reply, in this task. but the main reason for this is to restrict the user for accessing his/her facebook personal account allowing access only to our Client's facebook account.

Comment: Looks like you did not understand what I said, so again: Facebook loads a lot of JavaScript, CSS and data when you access any page – and those resources are not loaded from an address that begins with `www.facebook.com/ChildURL`, but from `www.facebook.com/ajax/`, `www.facebook.com/images/` (and even totally different CDN domains). So if you block anything that does not start with `www.facebook.com/ChildURL`, the user will be left with only a carcass of a page with basically no working functionality at all.